# How microgravity in space affects body parts

Tags: gravity

There are things that naturally face downwards, like hands. How would they be affected in space microgravity? Would they rise or point downwards?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking but this may be related: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/21755/6944

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ["neutral body posture"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutral_body_posture) in weightlessness tends to lift the arms and flex the knees slightly. Palms generally face downward. It varies person to person; here's a sample of 6 space shuttle astronauts from STS-57:

[image: computer renderings of four men and two women with knees slightly bent arms drifting at various heights from hip level to shoulder level]