# Do astronauts on the ISS have to consciously keep their arms down?

Tags: iss, astronauts, sleep, free-fall

After seeing many images of astronauts on the ISS sleeping, with their arms floating,

[image: Astronaut Luca Parmitano sleeps in his berth on board the ISS. Credits: ESA]

and Chris Hadfield describing arms floating up and head titling forward [How Do You Sleep In Space? | Video](https://youtu.be/T1hWJfsoiKw?t=61) I wondered, do astronauts in free fall have to consciously keep their arms down and head back while they are awake, but not engaged in an activity?

Comment: Highly related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/21750/why-do-iss-crew-members-often-cross-their-arms

Comment: Closely related: [How microgravity in space affects body parts](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/36842/how-microgravity-in-space-affects-body-parts)

Comment: I’d guess it’s about the same as what you feel underwater; it’s really easy to move your arms but their natural position is out if they go slack